# Embedding UITableView within UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I've got a UIView within a UIScrollView, both of which I've created programmatically. The white rectangle is the UIView.

[image]

I want to put a UITableView within the UIView so that they're roughly the same size, except I'd like to leave room for the title at the top of the view. Here's what I've tried:

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: view1.bounds)
    view1.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.center(in: view1)
    tableView.rowHeight = 30
    tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Except nothing shows up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you adding content to each row? I may not understand the question fully, although from what I understand you'll either need to specify the number of rows (if fixed) or use the cellForRowAt method to populate each table cell. This could be why the tableView isn't appearing, if there is no content it won't show anything.

Comment: @ColbyHill Yes, I'm going to add content to the rows, but my understanding was that even without content, you can still see the cells?

Comment: @ColbyHill also even when I tried adding text, nothing showed.

Comment: What's "My Family"? What's `center(in:)`?

Comment: @matt that is part of a cocoapod called Tiny Constraints. It just constrains the table view to the center of the view.

Comment: But if you use constraints, the frame will become zero. So that’s the problem. I bet if you cut that line you will see the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not instantiating your UIView with a `frame:` argument, you need to do so. Everything will seem normal if you omit this, and simply use the `view1.size()` method, except for some reason the tableView will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and I could see the table view.

```
    let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
    self.view.addSubview(uiView)

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: uiView.bounds)
    uiView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.rowHeight = 30
    tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
    tableView.separatorColor = .black
```

Below is my result :

[image]

You have to remove line ***tableView.center(in: view1)***

Comment: Unfortunately, removing that line did not solve the problem. The table view still does not appear.